# Display Phone Screen on a Raspberry Pi Touch Screen Display

Tags: pi-2, pi-3

Hi everyone while thinking of different concepts for a car deck I came to an idea that if only I could just Mirror my phones display onto a larger screen in the dash I would have everything needed rather than paying for an expensive replacement deck. Cause then I will have all my notifications and calls available as well as media entertainment.

So I thought about just getting a Touch Screen (so that I can input touch to my phone) and connecting it to a Raspberry Pi. And connect a Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter into the Raspberry Pi and mirror my phone to it.

Would this be possible? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically yes it would be possible but in reality lag would be a huge issue. Because of latency between whatever protocol you use. Furthermore audio would probably never work well as it requires a very low latency of processing for phone calls to not sound choppy. If you want to use your phone wouldn't it make more sense to simply buy a mount and stick it on the dash?

Comment: It would still be the small size screen of the mobile phone, which sometimes gets really distracting while driving as such :)

Comment: I'd recommend you just buy a tablet and mount that on the dash, there are a lot of android apps out there to allow your tablet to act as a carputer